# Can you filter a List webPart by URL in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to filter a List Webpart on a page by setting parameters on a URL?

Something like:
https://myspsite.test.com/sites/Testsite/SitePages/testPage.aspx?Model=1

Where testPage has a couple of list webparts but the first shows available models filtered by the value in the URL.

If so, how would you make sure that the right WebPart is affected.  I cant see a way of tagging each webpart.

I know I could create various views but there is a significant number of models that would make this very hard work (even if it was possible!)

Comment: As per my knowledge it's not possible

Comment: Thanks @KalpeshVaghela.  If anyone does find a way I'd be very interested.